# Click and hover collision

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-click-event

I'm using Bootstrap and have a problem using jQuery. I have a navigation bar at the header and I want that every link gets a different color when the mouse's surfed over a link and when the glyphicon-plus is clicked. It works well until I click the glyphicon and click it again. From that point on, the hover function doesn't work on the glyphicon again.

How can I fix it?

```js
var toggleState = true;
$('.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function() {
  if (toggleState) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#395ECC");
    $(this).css("border-radius", "5px");
  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#4775FF");
    $(this).css("border-radius", "0px");
  }
  toggleState = !toggleState;
});

$(".navbar li").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#395ECC");
  $(this).css("border-radius", "5px");
}, function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#4775FF");
  $(this).css("border-radius", "0px");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" title="Home">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> 
            </a>
          </div> 
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"><b class="caret"></b></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a></li>
                <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
                <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
        </nav>
```

Comment: There's no `navbar` class in your HTML.

Comment: There's nothing in `.dropdown-toggle` to click on.

Comment: I would highly recommend using CSS instead of jQuery. Bootstrap already changes the color when you're hovering or when the dropdown is active (you've clicked on it). Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ if you want to change the colors. It will save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Comment: .dropdown-toggle is a glyphicon and yes you can click it.

Comment: @redbmk I'm using Bootstrap CDN, I didn't want to download it when I started, I know it'd be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using LESS or at the very least generating a custom CSS with the colors you want from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. The reason main reason is that the following 5-line code change:

[image: small LESS diff]

results in this difference in CSS:

```css
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #4775ff;
    border-color: #265cff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #395ecc;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    border-radius: 5px
  }
```

You can just add that in as custom CSS, but other very simple changes will end up making big differences in the generated CSS. If you want the end result to look nice you'll need to account for all the different scenarios that bootstrap provides. For example, with this snippet the default font color is hard to see against the new background color.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" title="Home">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> 
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"><b class="caret"></b></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="divider"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><small><b>Link</b></small></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
<style>
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #4775ff;
    border-color: #265cff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #395ecc;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    border-radius: 5px
  }
</style>
```